# Headphones detected even though unplugged

Tags: 20.04, sound, headphones, speakers

I don't rely on headphones, and it was a very long while since me using them, but yesterday I had a problem of sound getting muted, I found headphones detected, and after that the computer would switch between headphones (no sound) and speakers like crazy and randomly. I use Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Since you do not say what make or model of headphones or how they are connected all anyone can do is guess. My guess the 3.5 mm connector has an issue.

Comment: @David I don't use headphones at all (so unplugged), but it shows me now that I do. I want to be able to get the inbuilt speakers to work again, so that's the issue.

Comment: And that issue, as already mentioned, is likely to be HARDWARE, nothing to do with the OS.